# Performance of code while adding and then comparing values

Tags: performance, kotlin, memory-management

The problem here is: I have to add two numbers and then do 3 operations with that sum. So either i add them both and put their value inside one variable and compute operations or i re-add like(a+b<c) while doing any operation. So which way is more memory efficient and fast?

```
 val sum  = k+d
 if(sum<=b && sum>spend){
    spend = sum
 }
```

or,

```
if(k+d<=b && k+d>spend){
   spend = k+d
}
```

Comment: Have you done any performance testing?  That would show you which is faster -- or, more likely, show that the difference is insignificant.

Comment: where can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context.  If `k` and `d` happen to be compile-time constants then the compiler can just replace `k+d` with the sum so it won't matter how many times you write `k+d`.  Also if the second form would turn out to be faster and the `sum` variable would not escape the function (not returned or used as parameter to other functions) then the compiler could replace `sum` with `k+d` and again it would make no difference.  Compiler optimization is usually pretty good so I don't think you should worry about it.

Since the first is clearer you should go for that, but you can always benchmark (make sure not to use compile-time constants then, as the sums will get optimized away) and tune if that piece of could would turn out to be a bottleneck.